# Qlikview Current selections box to use labels rather than table.fieldnames

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

In my Qlik View document I want to change the Current Selections information to use the Label applied to the field rather than the table.field format.

For example

> PartsTable.PartNo

Would be

> Part Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this in the Current Selections object. However, you may have some alternatives depending on your requirements.

First of all, if you're just happy with seeing the current selections as text (rather than having the functionality of the Current Selections object), you can create a Text object and use the expression:

```
=replace(GetCurrentSelections(), 'PartsTable.PartNo', 'Part Number')
```

This will then look something like the below:

[image: QlikView Text Object and List Box for PartsTable.PartNo]

The other alternative is to use the `RENAME` statement in the load script after all your table loads are complete. `RENAME` allows you to rename a single field or a collection of fields by using a mapping table. The syntax for a single field is shown below:

```
RENAME FIELD oldname to newname
```

If you should need to rename more than one field at a time, you can expand this to:

```
RENAME FIELD oldname1 to newname1, oldname2 to newname2,...
```

More detail on the syntax including using a mapping table can be found in the QlikView installed help file.

For your example, I put together a small demo:

```
QUALIFY *;

PartsTable:
LOAD * INLINE [
    PartNo
    100
    200
    300
];

UNQUALIFY *;

RENAME FIELD PartsTable.PartNo to [Part Number];
```

This then results in:

[image: The renamed field alongside a current selections object]

`RENAME` is similar to the alias (`AS`) statement, except that you can first load all of your data, and then do the rename at the end. This will then rename your field so that it appears under its new name in any front-end controls (e.g. Current Selections etc.) However, this may not be suitable for you if you already have an existing field named `Part Number` in your script.